# Look up date from range1 in range2 -> If match then color cell

Tags: vba, excel, calendar

To organize my projects, I created a calendar in an Excel sheet.

The dates are not fixed and differ from project to project. Certain dates should be colored in different ways. I use conditional formatting, but I find CF to not always work as I want it to. Besides, since I do a lot of copying & pasting, the CF rules add up enormously over time, slowing down the worksheet. VBA might also be more flexible in the end.

I started with coloring the cell containing today's date. I modified code from another website.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Dates As Range
    Set Dates = Range("B2:H2," & _
                        "B6:H6")
                        
    For Each cell In Dates
    
        If Not IsDate(cell.Value) Then
        End If
    
        If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
        End If
        
        If cell.Value = Date Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
      
        'Include more conditions e.g. lookup date in list of holidays; if date = holiday then different color

        ElseIf cell.Value - Date <> 0 Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
 
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Now I'd like to compare the dates in the range.1 "Dates" with a list of other dates (range.2) (e.g. holidays). If a cell from "Dates" matches with a cell from range.2, the cell that matches is supposed to get another color.

I tried to do it manually by adding

```
ElseIf cell.Value = cell(1, 1).Value Then
    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
```

However, this colors all cells, not only the cell that matches the date in cell(1, 1).

Comment: I would suggest not using `cell` as your variable name as it's an excel reserved work. Try renaming your variable

Comment: Thanks, good general advice, but this does not have an impact on my code, as it is now, correct?

Comment: How do "range.1" and "range.2" relate to what you coded so far? I do not really get what you are trying to do.

Comment: range1 is the range of my calendar, where all the dates are.
range2 is another range, where e.g. all holidays are listed.

Now the dates from the calendar (range1) are supposed to be compared to the dates in range2 (holidays). If there is a match (date in calendar = holiday), the cell is supposed to be colored.

Sorry for being totally clear. Is it understandable now?

Comment: My question was, what are range1 and range2 in terms of your code. What the values in the spreadsheet isnt of much relevance in this context. BTW, what you were doing with reference to `cell(1,1)` most probably didnt work because you handled the case of the date being other than today (`ElseIf cell.Value - Date <> 0 Then`) before, thereby coloring all of these cells.

EDIT: Also, those if-clauses checking for emptiness dont do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example; the code checks values in `ColA` to values in `ColB`, and if a match is found, colors the cell in `ColA`, Change the references as desired.

```
Dim xcel As Range
Dim ycel As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each xcel In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        For Each ycel In .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
            If xcel.Value = ycel.Value Then
                xcel.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            End If
        Next ycel
    Next xcel
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to use this code and include it into my code so that not only todays date is colored but additionally every date found in a specified range.

Comment: I was glad to help

Answer (score 0):

If you define range1 and range2 appropriately, the following will do the trick:

```
Sub colorCells()
    Set range1 = Range("B1:B5")
    Set range2 = Range("F1:F15")
    For Each cel In range2
        Set found = range1.Find(cel.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If found Is Nothing Then
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        Else
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: For your code to work, the dates have to be formatted as "m/d/yyyy". If you want it to recognize other date formats use `LookIn:=xlFormulas`.

Comment: No, with my Excel they definitely do not have to. But, they have to be formatted the same way. If there is any chance dates might get formatted inconsistently, I would rather use `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookUp`, as Find with `LookIn:=xlValues` strangely compares string values instead of the actual ones. But `LookIn:=xlFormulas` does not help, as it searches the cell's (unevaluated) formula. To me, this makes no sense in this context at all (and does not work with my test data, either).

Comment: I tried this code also and it worked just fine. However, I ended up using the other code (GMalc) since I found it a bit more intuitive. Thank you anyways. It's also very helpful to see different solutions for one problem.